# why isn't firewalld blocking ports that aren't open?

Tags: firewalld

I have the following zone for my internal network:

```
internal (active)
  target: default
  ingress-priority: 0
  egress-priority: 0
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp1s0f0
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client dns mdns samba-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

I only have a few services enabled for testing but if I run a web server on any port e.g. 8080 then `curl http://serverip:8080` I get a response from the web server. The `firewalld` service is showing as running on the machine but isn't blocking access to port 8080 despite it not being listed above.

How can I debug why this isn't working as intended?

- enp1s0f0 is definitely the correct interface
- the firewalld service is running via systemd and showing as running

Here's my iptables -S output:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-N DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-d8adea070e26 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-d8adea070e26 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-d8adea070e26 ! -o br-d8adea070e26 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-d8adea070e26 -o br-d8adea070e26 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d8adea070e26 -o br-d8adea070e26 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.19.0.2/32 ! -i br-d8adea070e26 -o br-d8adea070e26 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6789 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p udp -m udp --dport 5514 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p udp -m udp --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p udp -m udp --dport 10001 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8843 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.2/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p udp -m udp --dport 3478 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
```

I have services running in docker but it's not just services in docker that are accessible if I run `php -S 192.168.2.1:8000` on the machine itself (not in a container) then `curl 192.168.2.1:8000` on another machine on the network I get a response from the php server.

Comment: Are you running `curl http://serverip:8080` from the server itself?

Comment: no sorry, I should have said, it's running from a PC connected to the server via a switch connected to `enp1s0f0`

Comment: Thank you for adding the iptables -S output. There is no obvious evidence in that ruleset that shows that firewalld hs created any iptables rules. Currently there aren't any actual  rules in the INPUT chain and  the policy  `-P INPUT ACCEPT` is to allow all traffic.